# lookup not working with cell of over 256 characters

Tags: excel-formula, lookup

I am using the following formula to find the last cell with data in Column AA (between AA10:AA500) from another sheet. This works great until the text is over 256 characters and then it displays nothing. Is there a way around this issue? I need to display the result even when the text is over 256 characters.

=LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),'Mail Machine QR Data'!AA10:AA500)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround:

```
=INDEX(AA:AA,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(AA10:AA500)/(AA10:AA500<>""),1))
```

[image]

Comment: The above workaround does not work It returns an error of #NUM!  Keep in mind this a text not numbers that I am trying to pull.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I appreciate the help! Problem solved!

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer